# JS redirect after got request

Tags: javascript

Here is my code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     function httpGet(theUrl) {
         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
         xmlHttp.send( null );
         return xmlHttp.responseText;
     }
     function autoUpdate() {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
         coords = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
          url = "https://example.com/logme/" + coords;
         httpGet(url);
         console.log('should be working');
         setTimeout(autoUpdate, 2000);
     })
     };
     $(document).ready(function(){
        autoUpdate();
     });
  </script>
```

can anyone helps me  redirect user after I got `httpGet(url);`

(need `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` )

Comment: Please tell us the exact issue in your question.

Comment: https://track.bortnik.top =>  i need redirect JUST after you allowed me your location.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a different page using javascript, you can update the window's location with `window.location = 'https://www.some-website.com/';`

Comment: https://track.bortnik.top > i need redirect JUST after you allowed me your location.

Comment: That's what the callback function is for in `getCurrentPosition`. That will let you know that the user has responded to the request.

Comment: unfortunatelly, i dont understand you, i dont know js ;-( Can you give me  works code or examples?

Comment: Give [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) a read.